# How to cast Local Video using google cast sdk on iOS Sender

Tags: google-cast

searched for similar issues in this forum, and in the previous replies, someone suggested to embed a webService in iOS platform to implement it, but last year someone suggested to use MediaStore (but this does not apply to the iOS platform, and there is no following in the reply)

I checked google's relevant documents, but I didn't find any API that can implement casting local video/image, maybe I didn't read them carefully enough.

Do you have a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

With the way that senders work, you are expected to implement your own local player. The requirements that your app needs to meet then is to ensure that you are able to transition from the local player to the cast device and vice versa. I would suggest you to look at the cast videos sample for reference. We use a simple AVPlayer in the sample: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios/blob/master/CastVideos-swift/Classes/LocalPlayerView.swift